# How can Rock Lee stand on water?

Tags: naruto

According to what I have seen, Rock lee isn't able to use ninjutsu nor genjutsu. However, it was shown that he can walk on water. Isn't walking on water a part of chakra control which he isn't able to perform? If he can control chakra then why not perform ninjutsu (doesn't need to be good at it, but at-least perform it.)

Also I am unable to understand how can he open the inner gates of chakra if chakra control is a problem for him?

Comment: If im not mistaking, He's just cant change the shapes of chakra (forgot what it's called) but he's still can control his charka to open the 8 gates, for walking on water it's doesn't need to change the shapes, just control the chakra around his foot

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Chakra Control**

There are three things about Chakra Control.

1. Power Manipulation

   This is my own term. It refers to how much Chakra you mold upon performing a jutsu. Quoting [Wikia](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Chakra),

   > In order to have good chakra control, a ninja should only mould as much chakra as they need to perform a given ability. If they mould more chakra than is needed, the excess chakra is wasted and they will tire out faster from its loss. If they don't mould enough chakra, a technique will not be performed effectively, if at all, likely creating problems in a combat situation.
2. Shape Manipulation

   > Shape transformation deals with controlling the form, movement, and potency of chakra.
3. Nature Manipulation

   > Nature transformation deals with changing the physical properties of chakra into an element. There is also the nature transformation of Yin and Yang, which deals with changing the ratio of spiritual and physical energies within chakra.

**Rock Lee**

What Rock Lee was incapable of is the last two, Shape Manipulation and Nature Manipulation. Most Ninjutsu requires at least one of these two. For example, Katon: Goukakyu no Jutsu (Fire Style: Fireball Jutsu) requires both shape manipulation (to make it into ball) and nature manipulation to give fire element to the jutsu. Rasengan requires shape manipulation to make it into ball shape, although in a whole different level than Goukakyu no Jutsu. Chidori requires nature manipulation to add lightning element to the jutsu.

It has been consistently shown that Rock Lee was unable to perform the last two in that he was never shown to use any jutsu that requires them. He, however, was shown to be able to perform Power Manipulation. This is evident in his use of the 8 Gates which requires him to flow chakra to various spots in his body.

Standing on water requires Power Manipulation, that is, creating enough chakra to cover his feet palms to keep him afloat. It doesn't require shape nor nature manipulation, thus explains how Rock Lee can stand on water.

Comment: Excellent answer. To add to this, the Iron Fist style Lee and Guy uses are the same as that of Sakura. They can release Chakra from the palms at the moment of impact to increase the destructive force. The physical moves are not only muscle strength but Chakra too, and hence Taijutsu utilizes Chakra as well.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge there are varying levels of Chakra control that the ninja are able to use. Simple controls, like being able to focus chakra in on area, such as the feet in order to stand on top of water, are low level and even Rock Lee would have access to this, though he may have had to train a bit harder to get there.

Rock Lee is only unable to perform the more difficult chakra transformations that would allow him to use various skills and abilities, which is why he focuses on physical combat.

Answer (score 0):

It is my understanding that Rock Lee is not incapable of channeling chakra. he simply has no natural talent at either ninjutsu or genjutsu. Ninjutsu was defined in the show as a combination of Shape manipulation and Nature manipulation.

> hence why the Rasengan is considered an incomplete technique.

A genjutsu is created when a ninja controls the chakra flow of a target's cerebral nervous system, thereby affecting their five senses. In other words the caster uses their chakra to directly influence the mind of the target, effectively forcing them to hallucinate.

As water-walking is not a technique per se, but instead just a manipulation of chakra, Lee can do that.

If you are looking for the OFFICIAL answer however, I advise giving up now. No clear reason was given.

Comment: "Ninjutsu was defined in the show as a combination of Shape manipulation and Nature manipulation." This is not really true, the rasengan is ninjutsu but is shape manipulation only.

Comment: The Rasengan was referred to as incomlete due to the fact that it lacks nature manipulation by Kakashi while Naruto was learning how to use the wind element in Naruto: Shippuden.